# expression must be a modifiable lvalue: error after assigning a value to a char variable

Tags: c

```
void main()
{
    srand(time(0));
    char me, comp;
    char compStr[20];
    int compChoice = rand() % (2 + 1);
    if (compChoice == 0)
    {
        comp = 's';
        compStr = "Snake"; // THE ERROR IS SHOWN HERE
    }
    else if (compChoice == 1)
    {
        comp = 'w';
        compStr = "Water"; // THE ERROR IS ALSO SHOWN HERE
    }
    else if (compChoice == 2)
    {
        comp = 'g';
    }

    printf("Snake, Water or Gun? (s/w/g): \n");
    scanf("%c", &me);
    int result = snakeWaterGun(me, comp);
    if (result == 0)
    {
        printf("The game is draw!");
    }
    else if (result == 1)
    {
        printf("You Won!");
    }
    else if (result == -1)
    {
        printf("You lost! Computer Won. Computer chose %c", comp);
    }
}
```

VS Code is throwing an error after I assigned a char variable named 'compStr' a value, why is that?
P.s This code also has a function, but to improve readability, I haven't included it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An array can't be assigned to directly, although you can assign to individual members.

If you want to copy a string into a `char` array, use `strcpy`:

```
strcpy(compStr,"Snake");
```